# How to forward request IP from NGINX to node.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, nginx

I have NGINX running as reverse proxy which forwards all http and https traffic to my node.js application, which listens to localhost:port

However the issue I have is that the node.js application sees all incoming requests as coming from ::ffff:127.0.0.1

How can I change the NGINX config such that the real IP will be passed through and forwarded to the node.js application?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:myport;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

 # Requests for socket.io are passed on to Node on port x
  location ~* \.io {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:myport;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}


}
```

Edit: The express.js/node.js application processes req.ip and has app.enable('trust proxy'); at startup

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr` I think you already get it right. You should be able to read the real IP from "X-Real-IP" header. What's wrong now?

Comment: How does your nodejs app read IP?

Comment: Thx for your answers. From req.ip

Comment: I believe you're talking specifically about "express.js app" in place of any general "node.js app". I'd suggest mod your question to reflect this point.

Comment: Also I believe you've read this [guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html). Look like you've got most things right except one: in nginx conf you `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`. I believe the right answer should be `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Express.js official site has this [guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html). Instructions:

1. `app.set('trust proxy', true)` in js.
2. `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr` in nginx.conf
3. You can now read-off the client IP address from `req.ip` property

Comment: Do you actually mean "app.set" or really "app.enable"? Because in the official express documentation I can only find it with "app.set".


Btw.: Any ideas what could be the reason when I edited my nginx config (and restarted of course) and added app.enable('trust proxy') (also tried with app.set) and there are no changes. Can you somehow debug if the configuration even had any effect?

Comment: Finally accomplished it. I had to use "app.set('trust proxy', true)" (instead of true you could use the IP address of the reverse proxy - nginx). 




And I had to set the nginx.conf in nginx/sites-available/default in the server section instead of nginx.conf.

Comment: Changed from
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
TO
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
And once again able to get the REAL IP address in code using req.ip.

Answer (score 2):

This solves it taking into consideration above NGINX config.

```
var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```