# Can't get client's IP in production because of reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, ip, reverse-proxy

my nodejs backend application was running well in development. But now I realized that since in development I have a reverse-proxy from my front-end to all requests to /api, all the `req.ip` values are now localhost.

How can I solve it without using a third party api? Looks like I will need to get the client's ip before it arrives to the backend?

I am using nginx for the reverse proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward request IP from NGINX to node.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570505/how-to-forward-request-ip-from-nginx-to-node-js-application)

Comment: Yes, perfect. thank you

Answer (score 1):

as per Benard's suggestion, I had to add the following line to the express server file:

server.set("trust proxy", true);

then, in the nginx config:

```
  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; // added this
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
  }
```

restart the nginx and the express server, and req.ip will work.